# Single Sign-On For Magento And joomla

Tags: magento-1.9

I have magento and joomla sites same saver.I need to implement single sign in for both sites.any user login via joomla can access magento as log in user and.any user login via magento can access joomla site as logged  in user  .

i haven't any idea about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following module, it might help you or you may get an idea as well:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/yireo-magebridge-for-joomla.html

**This module is known as "MageBridge" which allows you to use Magento inside the Joomla!**